# Программирование и сети

Tags: сеть

Какой минимум знаний о сетевых технологиях нужен программисту?
Знаю что вопрос из спорных, но мне нужно на что-то ориентироваться.
Речь идёт не только о веб-разработке, а вообще о программировании.

Comment: Нашёл один похожий вопрос: [Хороший и краткий учебник по компьютерным сетям][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/148040/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC

Answer (score 2):

Это сильно зависит от прикладной области. Есть программисты, которым эти знания вообще не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Если интересуют сети как средство передачи информации между компьютерами - почитайте про сокеты, если помимо прикладных знаний хочется теории - то про протоколы передачи данных.

Для веб-разработки есть смысл выбрать технологию и именно про неё читать.